# Can 'such as' be used in introducing people

Tags: word-usage

Is this sentence grammatically correct: Enlightenment theorists such as Rousseau, Hobbes and Locke . . . I am confused regarding the use of such as. Can it be used for people in academic essays?

Regards,

Comment: Please explain why you are confused. I see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Well, you can get an objection to just about anything in an academic essay, but in common formal language using "such as" in the fashion you describe is perfectly fine.

Comment: I am unsure about using it with reference to people. The examples I found mostly deal with things, so I was wondering if it is to be used for people also.

Comment: Oh, okay. Yes, you can use 'such' with people.

Comment: Yes, there are cases where certain idioms are discouraged when referring to people vs inanimate objects, and other expressions are better.  But "such as" does not fall into this category, to my knowledge.  There are other ways to word the meaning, of course, but there is, that I know of, no reasonably direct replacement for "such as" that is more "human-appropriate".

Comment: In fact you could say, "Such Enlightenment theorists as Rousseau, Hobbes and Locke..." and it would probably sound better.

Comment: "such as" or "like" may be both used and are as frequent: [see ngram usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=persons+such+as%2Cpersons+like&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersons%20such%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersons%20like%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "... people such as A, B and C." merely means "... people, of which examples are A, B and C." or "people exemplified by A, B and C." As such (meaning "as in these examples") it is clear and correct English and is fit for formal or even legal discussion of people as well as things, circumstances, descriptions or anything else you like.